# How do I go about targeting the literal "first-child" of a div, styling depending on element type

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm creating custom CSS for a website and I'm coming across an issue regarding applying CSS to first-child of div. I'm trying to have special CSS style the actual first child only, depending on the element type it is, and the style is specific to that element's type. So, only if the article's very first element (within an div) is an image, then it ignores article margins. If the article's very first element is a paragraph, it creates an additional margin-top. Any thing that is not a literally first (non-div) element should not have any first-child rules applied.

I would like to do this by only using CSS if possible as I can only apply CSS to the existing HTML.

This is probably confusing. This [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n2umsy48/) uses a very similar setup to my html, and I've created a CSS that shows my error. I understand I'm not selecting the correctly nested div, I'm just not sure how to achieve what I want. In the fiddle, every element after a different element type has a first-child rules re-applied. Which again is due to me being unsure which div to reference.

Here's my code again:

HTML:

```
<article>
<div class="body entry-content">
    <div class="sqs-layout sqs-grid-12 columns-12">
        <div class="col sqs-col-12 span-12">

            <div class="sqs-block image-block sqs-block-image">
                <div class="sqs-block-content">
                    <div class="image-block-outer-wrapper">
                        <div class="intrinsic">
                            <div class="image-block-wrapper">
                                <img src="http://media.npr.org/images/picture-show-flickr-promo.jpg" alt="image"></img>


            <div class="sqs-block markdown-block sqs-block-markdown">
                <div class="sqs-block-content">
                    <p>p1</p>
                    <p>p2</p>
                    <p>p3</p>
                </div>
            </div>
                                </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="sqs-block markdown-block sqs-block-markdown">
                <div class="sqs-block-content">
                    <p>p1</p>
                    <p>p2</p>
                    <p>p3</p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="sqs-block image-block sqs-block-image">
                <div class="sqs-block-content">
                    <div class="image-block-outer-wrapper layout-caption-hidden">
                        <div class="intrinsic">
                            <div class="image-block-wrapper has-aspect-ratio">
                                <img src="http://media.npr.org/images/picture-show-flickr-promo.jpg" alt="image"></img>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="sqs-block markdown-block sqs-block-markdown">
                <div class="sqs-block-content">
                    <p>p1</p>
                    <p>p2</p>
                    <p>p3</p>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
    article {  
background-color:red;
padding:14px;
}
.body.entry-content {
padding:0px;
background-color:grey;
}
.body.entry-content p, img {
padding:0px;
margin:0px;
margin-bottom:1em;
}
.body.entry-content p:first-child{
    /* Only the first paragraph in an article confines to red margine and creates an extra margin-top to space the content further from the title (not seen here). */
margin-top:1em;
background-color:blue;
}
.body.entry-content img:first-child {
/* Only the first image in an article ignores all red margins, filling the article.*/
margin:-14px -14px 0px -14px;
}
```

Comment: article doesn't have margins in the markup above, just padding.  Does it typically have margins too?

Comment: Oh, that's my mistake. It should say red padding. The jsfiddle code is correctly written, I believe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible, but all those nested divs make it really ugly :

```
.body.entry-content div:first-child div:first-child div:first-child .sqs-block-content > p:first-child{
    background-color:blue;
}
.body.entry-content div:first-child div:first-child div:first-child .sqs-block-content div img:first-child {
    margin:-14px -14px 0px -14px;
}
```

[Fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/bobdye/x79zsho8/)

Comment: This actually works in my example, so that's awesome. You're right though the divs make it ugly. Unfortunately I don't have access to the html itself. And it turns out the CMS for my site generates different "articles" in different formats so this list of nested divs only works on a few types of entries. 

I somehow need to search '.body.entry-content' for the first div that contains a <p> or <img> first-child and apply my rules. Otherwise i'll have to specifically target the correct div in dozens of different 'entry types'.

Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

To reference the img, this worked for me - I think this selector is specific enough for you:

```
        .body.entry-content .sqs-layout div.image-block:first-child img {
            /* Only the first image in an article ignores all red margins, filling the article.*/
            margin: -14px -14px 0px -14px;
        }
```

Comment: I may be making a mistake, but when I use this the second image is also using the first-child code.